# Finding $A$ and $B$ such that $\sum_{n=A}^B(4n-7) = 39$ and $\sum_{n=1}^A (4n-7) = 12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

context: [sequence equation labeled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrhfD.png)

> Given that $$\sum_{n=A}^B(4n-7) = 39 \quad\text{and that}\quad
> \sum_{n=1}^A (4n-7) = 12$$
> find $A$ and $B$.

my attempt

For the 2nd equation's variable A first first $$\sum_{n=1} ^A (4n-7) = 12$$  $$u_1= (4 -7) = -3 $$
1,2,3,4,5
i was thinking of plugging in 4(5) -7 but it would equal 13 instead 12
$$\frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$$
$$\frac{n(-3 + 12)}{2}$$
n(9)/2
I dont really know what do with that, so tried $$ u_n =a_1 (n-1)d $$ instead
$$u_n= -3 (n-1) 1$$
so it would be $$ -3(n-1) = -3n +3$$
$$-3n +3 =12$$
$$-3n = 15$$
$$n=5$$
me trying to double check
$$\sum_{n=1} ^5 (4n-7) = 12$$

$$1,2,3,4,5$$
got -3, 1, 5, 9, 13 by putting each number (1,2,3,4,5) as n into $$(4n-7)$$
then i added them up but i got 25 instead 12
$$-3, 1, 5, 9, 13 =25$$
so , im not sure where to go from here.
ty for reading

Comment: In first two formulas index of summation is $n$, but general member of sum depends only on $x$. Typo?

Comment: 1) Is it $(\sum 4x)-7$ or $\sum (4x-7)?$ 2) Is it $4x$ or $4n?$

Comment: It was written 4x but i think 4n does makes more sense

Comment: @Anne Bauval ∑(4x−7)

Comment: As is written first two formulas contain $3$ variables $A, B, x$. If there should be $n$, then you have two variables in two equation and you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Comment: Pleas edit your post to clarify these two points, and to include your attempts. Since you "know how to evaluate" $\sum_{n=a}^bn$ (for any natural numbers $a\le b$) as a function of $a$ and $b,$ this should not be so difficult. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the first $n$ terms of an arithmetic sequence (progression) $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$$

We are given
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{A} (4n - 7) = 12$$
If $a_n = 4n - 7$, then $a_1 = 4 \cdot 1 - 7 = 4 - 7 = -3$ and $a_A = 4A - 7$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{A(-3 + 4A - 7)}{2} & = 12\\
\frac{A(4A - 10)}{2} & = 12\\
A(2A - 5) & = 12\\
2A^2 - 5A & = 12\\
2A^2 - 5A - 12 & = 0\\
2A^2 - 8A + 3A - 12 & = 0\\
2A(A - 4) + 3(A - 4) & = 0\\
(2A + 3)(A - 4) & = 0
\end{align*}
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of its factors is equal to zero,
\begin{align*}
2A + 3 & = 0 & \text{or} & & A - 4 & = 0\\
2A & = -3 & & & A & = 4\\
A & = -\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
Since $A$ must be a positive integer, the solution $A = -3/2$ is extraneous.  Hence, $A = 4$.

Therefore,
$$\sum_{n = A}^{B} (4n - 7) = \sum_{n = 4}^{B} (4n - 7) = 39$$
Observe that
$$\sum_{n = 4}^{B} (4n - 7) = \sum_{n = 1}^{B} (4n - 7) - \sum_{n = 1}^{3} (4n - 7)$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^{B} (4n - 7) - \sum_{n = 1}^{3} (4n - 7) & = 39\\
\frac{B(-3 + 4B - 7)}{2} - \frac{3(-3 + 5)}{2} & = 39\\
\frac{B(4B - 10)}{2} - \frac{3 \cdot 2}{2} & = 39\\
B(2B - 5) - 3 & = 39\\
2B^2 - 5B - 42 & = 0
\end{align*}
I will leave the remaining details to you.